# Passing JSON as a model object from my controller to a strongly typed view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, razor

I am building an asp.net mvc 4 web application that calls a web service provider then i am displaying the json result that is returned from the web services call using java script. for example on the controller level I have the following action method:-

```
public ActionResult ListPackages()
        {            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {                try
                {
                    var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
                    var url = new UriBuilder("http://localhost:8080/jw/web/json/workflow/package/list");
                    url.Query = query.ToString();
                    string json = client.DownloadString(url.ToString());
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                    return Content(json, "application/json");
                }
                catch (System.Net.WebException) {

                   return Content("error", "application/json");

                }           }        }
```

Then i am using a java script to display the JSON on the view:-

```
function getpackagelist(result) {
        $('#products').empty();
        $('#title').text("All Processes");
        $.each(result.data, function (key, val) {
            var str = val.packageName;
            $('<li/>', { text: str })
                .appendTo($('#products'));
        });
        $('#tobehide').hide();
```

and finally on the view i have the following code which calls the above action method and the java script:-

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
@Ajax.ActionLink("Get Process List", "ListPackages", "Home",
new AjaxOptions
    {    HttpMethod = "GET",
        LoadingElementId = "tobehide",
        OnBegin = "clear",

        OnFailure = "clear",
        OnSuccess = "getpackagelist"
    })
<div id= "geturl" data-url="@Url.Action("ListPackages", "Home")">
    <img class="hide" id="tobehide" src="~/Content/ajax-loading2.gif" />
<h1 id ="title"></h1>

<ul id="products">

</ul>
</div>
```

The above is working well, but i find it difficult to do the whole staff using javascript, so i am thinking of passing the JSON as a model to a strongly-typed view instead of using java script, but i have the following questions:-

1. what are the pros and cons of these two approaches (using javaScript versus passing the JSON to a strongly-typed view).
2. how I can pass the JSON as a model to my strongly-typed view.
3. which approach i should follow ??

Thanks in advance for any help.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

1.) Pro of using a strongly-typed view is that it works with SEO. Spiders can't execute javascript, they see whatever you see when you "view source" on your page. Pro of using javascript is that pages "seem" to load faster -- you may get better "perceived performance".

2.) You can do this:

```
// in controller action
...
string json = client.DownloadString(url.ToString());
dynamic asDynamic = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
return View(asDynamic);

@* in view *@
@model dynamic
Here is a value: @Model.SomePropertyOnYourJsonObject
```

3.) It depends. I don't think you provided enough information to describe which is the most appropriate decision for your circumstances.